# parsing html pages from tcl

Tags: html, dom, tcl, tdom

I using tdom version 0.8.2 to parse html pages.

From the help pages I found the following commands to get the ElementById

## TCL code

```
set html {<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="m"> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
}
package require tdom
set doc [ dom parse -html $html ] 
set node  [ $doc getElementById m]
```

But when I execute the second set command I get a empty string . But cleary the tag has an id of m . 
Can someone tell where am I going wrong ?

Regards,
Mithun

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your document lacks a `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration, so tDOM doesn't know that the `id` element is to be interpreted as an ID.

If we add a DOCTYPE, it all works...

```
package require tdom
set html {<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="m"> 
    </div>
  </body>
</html>}
set doc [ dom parse -html $html ] 
set node  [ $doc getElementById m]
puts [$node asList]
```

Produces this output for me:

```
div {id m} {}
```

You could have checked that the document was being parsed at all by doing a search to see if the element is findable using XPath, like this:

```
puts [[$doc selectNodes "//*\[@id\]"] asList]
```

Since that *did* produce the right output (as above) it was clear that the problem had to be in the interpretation of the attribute, which in turn pointed straight at the missing DOCTYPE.

---

## Update

It's actually a bug that was fixed in tDOM 0.8.3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Which tdom version are you using ?
For me this still does not work , as in "puts [[$doc selectNodes "//*\[@id\]"] asList] " the commands produces the same output . 
But the set node [$doc getElementById m]
 command does not work .

Comment: You need tDOM 0.8.3. Apparently (according to the changelog) it was a bug fixed on 2007-10-30.